# Move label grid to left of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Way out my comfort zone here, I dev in PHP ,Jquery etc, helping someone out in R-Studio. I have a plot where the label is between the Y axis and the plot area, I can use

```
facet_grid(producer~., switch="y", labeller = labeller(producer = label_wrap_gen(width = 50)))+
```

with the switch "z" to put the label on the right but this is as far as it will go on the left.

[image]

No doubt you will need more info but tbh I am not sure what else you would need. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: How about you rotate label 90 degrees? Won't solve the problem, but might look nice :)

Comment: Try `xlab("Fucus spiralis")`

Answer (score 2):

Sorted it. Thanks for suggestions but this is the perfect fix.

```
theme(strip.placement = "outside") +
```

Which Produced this -> [image]

Hope it helps others.

Regards

Keith